# Activity Monitor doesn't show main info?

Tags: high-sierra, activity-monitor

this happens only some times .

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

what changes is the info displayed in the lower portion of the window ,

what could be the issue?

Comment: is this the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302090/activity-monitor-show-no-processes ?