# Activity Monitor show no processes

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, cpu, activity-monitor, virtual-memory

With **10.13**.  I using Item2 to compile golang (`src/all.bash`). When cpu is get 100% The Item2 can't response. I have already open Activity Monitor. But I can't force quit the Item2.  Then I quit Activity Monitor and start again.
This time it show nothing.  Other graphic app Chrome and Pycharm work fine.

And I can't open Item2 and Terminal too.

I have Virtual Studio Code installed. And open it's "Integrated Termnial"(which I can have a zsh). I can `pwd`, But I can't `ps` and `top` (this mean it hang on don't return)

I can't open Dr Cleaner too. Something software related process monitor can work.

I also notice when the Item2 is not response. I see a process take a huge virtual memory.

Another things: I try to use Activity Monitor's tool "Running System Diagnostics" but it is always in running status and can't stop.

Comment: Exactly what is the contents of `src/all.bash` ? that might help seeing that to see why it's causing cpu to spike to 100%

Answer (score 2):

Did you have htop open? You might be experiencing this issue https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: I indeed often use htop. But I am not sure I open htop when it is crash. (I already reboot the machine) and you link is helpful (I don't think is htop related, So don't google about it)